# Generate PDF file using AJAX call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, pdf

I'm trying to generate a PDF file using AJAX call in Rails3. The following code generates a PDF file which I have created using PRAWN gem.

```
 <%= link_to "Generate pdf", books_path(@book, :format => 'pdf') %>
```

I do not want user to view the PDF until they order it. So, the goal is to create a PDF file in the server.

Any ideas or thoughts much appreciated.

Comment: Read above post again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Ariejan.
I modified your code as following and it did just what I wanted.

```
 <%= link_to "Generate Story Book", pdfbook_stories_path(:format => 'pdf'), :remote => true %>
```

And for the controller,

```
def pdfbook
    @stories = current_account.stories
    respond_to do |format|
        format.pdf {}
    end
```

end

Answer (score 1):

Use this, make sure your remote action does not return the PDF, but simple generates and stores it on the server.

```
link_to "Generate PDF", prepare_books_path(@book), :remote => true, :method => :put
```

This will work in Rails 3. If you're using jQuery, make sure to read [this article](http://www.simonecarletti.com/blog/2010/06/unobtrusive-javascript-in-rails-3/) on how to set things up correctly.

Your controller action may look like this:

```
def prepare
  # Do your thing to generate the PDF
  render :text => "PDF Generated", :status => 200
end
```

I used the PUT-method because you are altering the state of your data (e.g. you are generating something new, you don't want a bot or crawler to automatically call that).

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, it beats me why you would do something on a request like generating a PDF, when the user is not expecting that action. Isn't better to only generate the pdf when the user requests for it?

Comment: The scenario of my application is little different than what you are thinking Harish. And I don't feel its important to explain everything here. Thanks anyway.