# How to render Wicked PDF in a Bootstrap Modal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wicked-pdf

As you would know that PDFs can be generated using [Wicked PDF gem](https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf).
Normally, I render `format.pdf { render pdf: "pdf_filename" }` in a controller action.

How can I render the generated PDF in a Bootstrap's modal window ?

Comment: Maybe have a look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4384842/generate-pdf-file-using-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

You need to put an iframe in the modal and render the pdf if that iframe

Comment: Can you please provide a code sample to understand how pdf can be rendered in the iframe inside modal on the fly ?

Comment: `<iframe src="http://localhost:3000/user/123/report.pdf"></iframe>` and a `report` action in `UsersController` with `format.pdf { render pdf: "pdf_filename" }`

Comment: `UsersController` with `report` action (and `get "/user/:id/report" => "users#report"` route). Then `format.pdf { render pdf: "pdf_filename" }` in the `report` action

Comment: As I understand, you are rendering the pdf in the action itself. How that can be displayed in the modal using iframe ?

Comment: Because the link of the page with the modal and the link to the PDF in the iframe are different

Comment: I want to render the `pdf_filename` in the modal and from the above example of yours, its not clear to me. Can you please post a detailed answer?